# tslint / typescript: Prevent function nesting

Tags: typescript, tslint

Is there a way to use tslint to prevent function nesting?

```
export const function DontBeLateDate =
  (isDifferent: boolean) =>
    (additionalMilliseconds: Number) =>
      new Date((isDifferent ? 13378335 : 83351337) + additionalMilliseconds);
```

resulting in:

```
DontBeLateDate(true)(1024);
```

Issue being isDifferent is is used within a nested function.

**This should be valid:**

```
export const function DontBeLateDate =
  (isSomethingElse: boolean) => {
    if (isSomethingElse) {
      return (isDifferent: boolean, additionalMilliseconds: Number) =>
              new Date((isDifferent ? 5 : 7) +
              additionalMilliseconds);
    }
    return (isDifferent: boolean, additionalMilliseconds: Number) =>
      new Date((isDifferent ? 13378335 : 83351337) +
          additionalMilliseconds);
  }
```

isSomethingElse scope does not bleed into the inner function.

Comment: It's not clear what you want tslint to warn about here - curried functions (i.e. those called like `f(x)(y)`), or the creation of a closure (i.e. the local variables of the outer function being still available to the inner function after the outer function has returned)? Neither are normally considered mistakes or bad style.

Comment: Good point. Curried functions! That is the keyword I am looking for. But closure is the root issue. The latter.

Comment: Looks like there is a third-party project for this on GitHub, though it's a work-in-progress according to the readme. https://github.com/bafolts/tslint-no-closures

Comment: So we are getting ‘function(a)(b)(c)’ syntax. ‘Const f = Function(a); r = f(b); n = f(c); return n;’ would be much cleaner. But the closer issue is a problem for me. Proper classes satisfy curried functions. However, in javascript I have no issues with curried functions.

Comment: Perfect. Please post as an answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues here: the first one is [currying](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying), i.e. having a function which returns a function, so that it can be called like `f(x)(y)`. The second issue is creating a [closure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_programming)), i.e. the outer function has local variables which remain accessible by the inner function even after the outer function has returned.

In the comments you've said closures are what you'd like tslint to warn about. This can be achieved using a third-party tslint rule named [tslint-no-closures](https://github.com/bafolts/tslint-no-closures), which is available on GitHub. However, be aware that the README for this project currently says it is a work in progress.